# undefined method `id' for #<Calendar::ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar

Basically I'm trying to set to which calendar a `Trainer` would register for,like this:

```
@calendar = Calendar.where("current = 1")
@trainer.calendar = @calendar.id
```

and that gives me the following error:

```
undefined method `id' for #<Calendar::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000371d128>
```

why is that?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to get the first calendar with `current = 1`?

Comment: What is the relationship between `Trainer` and `Calendar` ?

Comment: @Anthony Calendar has_many trainers. And since there will be only one calendar that has a `current` of `1`, I wanna get that calendars id.

Comment: Isn't `current` a boolean field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will work :

```
@calendar = Calendar.where(current: 1)
@trainer.calendar = @calendar.first
```

`Calendar.where("current = 1")` gives `ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Calendar` object. You need to fetch the `Calendar` object, from that `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, then you can call the method `#id`.

Looking at the code, it seems you want to assign the `Calendar` object, so don't call `#id` method.

Comment: This gives me `Calendar(#70177389090900) expected, got Fixnum(#7632340)` error

Comment: @Xeen It will work.. Check and modify the Test case.

Comment: @ArupRakshit indeed, you have an error. It should be `@trainer.calendar = @calendar.first`. 
What's more, I don't think OP intention is to set `@calendar` as relation, like in your snippet.

Comment: @MarekLipka Yes.. I was looking into the `#id` method, and OP seems want to assign the `Calendar` object, so `id` call don't need.

Comment: This worked now, I'll accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Using `where`, you fetch a set of `Calendar` records (in `AR` terms, it's `ActiveRecord::Relation`) that fulfill given condition instead of single record. If you want to find singular `Calendar` record with `current = 1`, this will work:

```
@calendar = Calendar.find_by_current!(1)
@trainer.calendar = @calendar
```

Comment: Yes, your answer also worked, but I accepted Arups answer because his method worked before you edited your post. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Xeen yes, I wasn't sure what are your intentions until then. But it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can call method `.values` of ActiveRecord_Relation to get actual data.

```
@calendar = Calendar.where(current: 1).values
```

For better insight you can look into [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-values)